# How to dump json-like string without quoting keys?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Instead of this (from `json.dumps`):

```
[
  {
    "created": 581937573,
    "text": "asdf"
  },
  {
    "created": 581937699,
    "text": "asdf"
  }
]
```

I would like to get this [non-JSON] output:

```
[
  {
    created: 581937573,
    text: "asdf"
  },
  {
    created: 581937699,
    text: "asdf"
  }
]
```

If `json.dumps` had an option to change the quote character for keys, I could just set it to a placeholder and strip them out later. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to have this option... any other clever ideas?

(load from this format is not necessary, but would be interesting if a solution for it exists as well)

Comment: Note that although this is valid in JavaScript itself, it is *not* valid JSON.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`re.sub` offers a quick fix under certain assumptions:

```
import re

data = [...]
json_data = json.dumps(data)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(re.sub(r'"(.*?)"(?=:)', r'\1', json_data))
```

`file.txt`

```
[
  {
    created: 581937573,
    text: "asdf"
  },
  {
    created: 581937699,
    text: "asdf"
  }
]
```

These assumptions are

1. your data is small enough that `re.sub` runs in a reasonable amount of time
2. your data does not contain string values that themselves contain stuff that could match the pattern I've used here.

The pattern effectively looks for all dictionary keys and strips out the quotes.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. There's an extra bracket here `json_data)))`. Also, could you please briefly explain the regex part (`r'"(.*?)"(?=:)', r'\1'`) in plain words?

Comment: @dtgq thanks. It uses a regex to search for strings inside double quotes which also happen to have a colon following, and removes the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If solution by @cs95 doesn't work in your case (for example you have additional `"` in values), then you can use `jsonnetfmt` tool to do this. This is workaround, but it works very well.

`jsonnetfmt` will format it as jsonnet which in this case happens to be exactly what OP wanted. It is configurable a bit, run `jsonnetfmt --help` to check it.

(please notice additional commas in examples below, it is side effect of this method)

Install steps:

1. Install `go`
2. install `jsonnetfmt` by running:

```
go get github.com/google/go-jsonnet/cmd/jsonnetfmt
```

Running steps:

1. Save json to file.
2. Run `jsonnetfmt` on this file.
3. Read file.

```py
with open('json_file.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)


from subprocess import run
run('jsonnetfmt json_file.json --in-place')


with open('json_file.json', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    json_output= f.read()
```

Before:

```
[
  {
    "created": 581937573,
    "text": "asdf"
  },
  {
    "created": 581937699,
    "text": "asdf"
  }
]
```

After:

```
[
  {
    created: 581937573,
    text: 'asdf',
  },
  {
    created: 581937699,
    text: 'asdf',
  },
]
```

After with added `--string-style d`:

```
[
  {
    created: 581937573,
    text: "asdf",
  },
  {
    created: 581937699,
    text: "asdf",
  },
]
```